# Angular and Coffeescript cannot access app module in seperate files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, coffeescript

I'm trying to make multiple files to manage and refactor my angular code in a rails project with coffeescript. I think the coffeescript is making my angular objects inaccessible between files but not sure.
File structure:

```
javascripts
|-Angular
  |-controllers
  | |-search_strl.js.coffee
  |-main.js.coffee
|-application.js
```

In application.js: `//= require_tree ./angular`

In main.js.coffee:

`'use strict'; 
copassApp = angular.module 'copassApp', []`

In search_ctrl: `copassApp.controller('SearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'Cospace', 'Copasser', '$location', ($scope, Cospace, Copasser, $location) -> ...more code...`

Console error: Uncaught ReferenceError: copassApp is not defined

Not sure if this is a required file issue or a misuse of angular module or coffeescript not allowing cross-file object access. Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Compiled js after the suggested answer:

main.js.coffee:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var copassApp, root;

  copassApp = angular.module('copassApp', ['copassApp.SearchCtrl']);
  root = $('html');
  angular.bootstrap(root, ['copassApp']);
}).call(this);
```

search_strl.js.coffee:

```
(function() {
  angular.module('copassApp.SearchCtrl', ['$scope', 'Cospace', 'Copasser', '$location', function($scope, Cospace, Copasser, $location) {}]);
}).call(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay all is working now. Syntactically I would like to thank @theJoeBiz because my previous code was improperly composed.
I have the same file structure but here are the changes to the files.

main.js.coffee:

```
copassApp = angular.module 'Copass', ['Factories', 'Controllers', 'Directives']
factories = angular.module 'Factories', ['Cospace', 'Copasser', 'HtmlViewService']
...
```

search_ctrl.js.coffee

`angular.module('Search', []).controller('Search', [... ->`

I was thinking of `angular.module` as a getter and setter but is really only for initializing. I hope this answers questions of other people too.

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful to see the resulting javascript. My initial thought is that perhaps the search_ctrl.js is loading before main.js. You should also try to avoid declaring copassApp as a global variable and then accessing it from other files. The best practice is to use angular.module() in the separate files to access an existing module.

I don't know coffeescript, but an example in js would be...

main.js:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var copassApp = angular.module('copassApp', []);
})();
```

search_ctrl.js:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('copassApp').controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope)) {
    ...more code...
  });
})();
```

And then of course main.js needs to load before search_ctrl.js as stated above.

Another option is to use separate modules and require them in main.js so that file loading order doesn't matter.

main.js:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  var copassApp = angular.module('copassApp', ['copassApp.SearchCtrl']);
})();
```

search_ctrl.js:

```
(function() {
  'use strict';
  angular.module('copassApp.SearchCtrl', []).controller('SearchCtrl', function($scope)) {
    ...more code...
  });
})();
```

Comment: Looks like that helped but now seeing this and I tried playing with the loading order again. `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module copassApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module copassApp.SearchCtrl due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module $scope due to:
Error:...<omitted>...1)`

Comment: In debugging I found that I should remove `ng-app` and instead bootstrap to manually load. Check my edit for compiled js now, thanks.

Comment: So file order matters or not?